# How to find the correct condition for my matplotlib scatterplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to correlate two measures(DD & DRE) from a data set which contains many more columns. I created a data frame and called it as 'Data'.

Within this Data, I want to create a scatterplot between DD(X axis) & DRE(y Axis), I want to include DD values between 0 and 100.

Please help me with the first line of my code to get the condition of DD between 0 and 100
Also when I plot the scatterplot, I get dots beyond 100% ( Y axis is DRE in %) though I dont have any value >100%.

```
 Data1= Data[ Data['DD']<100]    
 plt.scatter(Data1.DD,Data1.DRE)
 tick_val = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
 tick_lab = ['0%','10%','20%','30%','40%','50%','60%','70%','80%','90%','100'] 
 plt.yticks(tick_val,tick_lab)
 plt.show()
```

Comment: Try `Data1= Data.loc[(Data['DD'] < 100]) & (Data['DD'] > 0)]` ?

Comment: Without the data this is hard to answer. Can you post a sample?

Comment: Thanks Evan, it works. another question. values in my Y axis are between 0% to 100%, but when I plot this chart I get values beyond 100% though I dont have any value like that, also how can I fit the Y axis ticks to cover the entire graph?